# How can use data in a row

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, node-sqlite3

I was trying to figure out how to use sqlite with Node JS. I don't get how we can use the row when we ask the data base what we want. I looked everywhere on the web but nobody explain really how to use the row after the get is done.

I mean it returns the row but I can't use it.

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

// open the database
let db = new sqlite3.Database('./db/chinook.db');

let sql = `SELECT PlaylistId id,
                  Name name
           FROM playlists
           WHERE PlaylistId  = ?`;
let playlistId = 1;

// first row only
var test = db.get(sql, [playlistId], (err, row) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err.message);
  }
  return row
    ? console.log(row.id, row.name)
    : console.log(`No playlist found with the id ${playlistId}`);

});

//What I added to try to use the row after the get is done
console.log(test.id) // I get "undefined" here. How are we really suppose to do it?

// close the database connection
db.close();
```

This code comes from [here](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/query/)

Comment: How do you know if it returns the row if you can't actually *use* it? And what do you mean by *use* - do you see the logs? By the way, aren't you closing the db connection prematurely? I believe you should do `db.close()` after you actually obtain the record (so, preferably within the callback, right?)

Comment: I don't know when to close the BD. I gess I need to do it when I am got my datas. By the way, with your comment, I edited a bit the thing so you can understand more easly what I mean by _use_

Answer (score 1):

try to use a Promise, for example:

```
const query = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   var test = db.get(sql, [playlistId], (err, row) => {
       if (err) {
          reject(err);
       }
       resolve(row);
   });
});

query
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: What does resolve mean?

And what does your 3 last lines of code?

Comment: Hi @YetiTheDev, with a Promise your process is asynchronous and in your example the process is synchronous and you can't return data from synchronous process. Therefore you need to wrap the synchronous process into the Promise, so you can catch the error and the result, then the process ended and you return the data in the resolve and when there some error it return in the reject. And in the 3 last lines you can print the data. Have you ever use a Promise?

Comment: I never used that. It is the first time that someone talk to me about that.